# C++ 2D vector maps

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

First of all, I know this question has been asked alot, but I need to clarify and understand some things. Also, I am still learning c++, currently from a book and tutorials, so don't be harsh :)

How can I have a 2D map for a platformer defined in code and modified? I understand basic multidimentional arrays, but I really can't use them because the size of my map will be changing alot. I can use a vector of vectors, but from what I have heard, this isn't a rectangular grid any more, it is more like...

```
x x x x x x x x x x   
x       x . . . . .
x       x . . . . .
x x x x x x x x x x
```

Where x is a tile, space is an air tile, and a dot is not allocated. Not a grid!

I am also confused on how pointers of arrays work.

Sorry for being abit of a noob here, I am still trying to work things out.

Any help would be greatly apprieciated!

Comment: It sounds like you want a resizable matrix class, which doesn't exist in the STL, to my knowledge.

Comment: Then any alternatives? All I want to do is store the level of my game :)

Comment: A vector of vectors will indeed work, as long as you are careful to keep all of the nested vectors the same size.

Comment: Thanks cdhowie, trying that now. I have std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> levelMap; in my map class now, but can you explain how I can edit this? I know I have to use .push_back, but not sure how I can go about this with a vector in vector. Can you post some code? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely go for a vector of vectors if you need a simple resizable matrix class. You can always wrap this into a `Matrix` class on your own (perhaps by templating the dimensions/types)

```
struct Tile {
    int whatever = 0;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> m;
    m.resize(10);
    for(auto& v : m)
        v.resize(10);

    // Print a 10x10 0-initialized matrix
    for(auto& v : m) {
        for(auto& elements : v)
            std::cout << elements.whatever << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://ideone.com/V6rURD)</kbd>

Memory in a vector is contiguously allocated, there are no "holes". Anyway you'll have to keep the dimensions of the inner vectors in sync if you resize one.

If you believe this is too much work for what you have in mind, go for Boost BLAS capabilities with [Matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm).

Comment: Thanks for that link, that might be the way to go. I am abit confused with vectors lol. I think until I read up on them more it might be better to use boost. If anyone else has any other ideas, please post :) Thanks Marco.

Comment: Alright, spent the last hour or so doing some proper reading on vectors of vectors, and I think I understand. I think I will be using this method to make my maps. Thankyou very very much! :D Accepted.

Comment: I promise it will be time well-spent :)